# Apply qt stylesheet to html elements of tooltip

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtstylesheets

I am trying to format the content of some `QToolTip` using stylesheets.

Setting a widget's stylesheet to

```
<h1>Title</h1>Content
```

produces the expected result, and I can style the tooltip with, for instance

```
QToolTip { color: red; }
```

to get red colored text. I am now trying to use the stylesheet for the `h1` inside the tooltip, but this produces no effect:

```
QToolTip h1 { color: blue; }
```

while setting it directly in the string works:

```
<h1 style='color: blue'>Title</h1>Content
```

Is there a way to perform this action with stylesheets? I tried using classes, but without success.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you trying to use is invalid, you can see a list of Selector Types [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

There is no way to select the <h1> of a QToolTip using style sheets, since it's not a Widget. You have to go for the other way you already pointed out.

Comment: Right, I missed this sentence: "The selector specifies which widgets are affected by the rule".